# c# data binding with a structure value

Tags: c#, data-binding

I need some help regarding a driver I`m building. I have a structure of some data in my static class. The data of this structure object has to be manipulated from outside my driver class. Into my class I have to prepare some textBoxes, which can be assigned and used from outside the class. Each structure value becomes one textBox. Now my problem is, I have to connect this dynamic changable structure values with the corresponding textBox. I have to use dataBinding, cause there will be a huge amount of data I have to use.

Pls check out the following code snippet for understanding:

```
    public static class driver
{

    #region " data preparation "

    //structure definition
    public struct _data
    {
        public string moduleName;
        public string dynamicNumber1;
        //...
    }

    //instance object of struct
    private _data moduleData = new _data();

    //get;set property
    public _data pModuleData
    {
        get
        {
            return moduleData;
        }
        set
        {
            moduleData = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    //build data binding(s) for each single "moduleData.structureItem"
    //???????????????????? moduleData_itemBinding_ModuleName
    //???????????????????? moduleData_itemBinding_dynamicNumber1
    //...

    #region " form elements preparation for external assignments "

    //instance of forms objects, data can be assigned and used outside of this public static class
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_ModuleName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_dynamicNumber1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();

    #endregion

            #region " class initialisation "

    static driver()
    {
            // class initialisation part   
        textBox_ModuleName.DataBindings = moduleData_itemBinding_ModuleName; //assign databindings from above ???????????
        textBox_ModuleName.DataBindings = moduleData_itemBinding_dynamicNumber1; //adding databindings from above ???????????
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: this driver class should enable other developers in my team to connect easely and fast some predefined textBoxes, connected with the described structure items. This structure will be filled by a special communication interface with a realtime controller. So for the moment it has to be a struct.. Also the textBox becomes some more settings into this class, so it has to be defined once, and outside the class all these propperties can be assigned to a placed textBox in an other form-class.  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

I think it is possible to make as follows. Define your class:

```
public class Driver
{
    public Driver(TextBox moduleName, TextBox dynamicNumber)
    {
        textBox_ModuleName = moduleName;
        textBox_DynamicNumber = dynamicNumber;

        textBox_ModuleName.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "ModuleName");
        textBox_DynamicNumber.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "DynamicNumber");
    }

    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string DynamicNumber { get; set; }

    private TextBox textBox_ModuleName;
    private TextBox textBox_DynamicNumber;
}
```

Then create textboxes on the form:

```
var textBox1 = new TextBox { Parent = this };
var textBox2 = new TextBox { Parent = this, Top = 30 };
```

Create instance of your class and pass to it these textboxes:

```
var driver = new Driver(textBox1, textBox2);
driver.ModuleName = "foo";
driver.DynamicNumber = "bar";
// data will be appear in the textboxes
```

It works.

Comment: Right this I was looking for, thank you very much for your good answer! Now just as interest, how the same can be made, if the example above would be a "public static class Driver" ? In case there would be a bigger nbr of data, how can be passed a single TextBox to add corresp DataBinding in a form?